# Passing data to UIbutton in custom cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a table view controller with custom cell. 
custom cell has got a button and some text label.
How can i pass the text data of the row to the button when clicked?

Answer (score 3):

1)In your cellForRowAtIndexPath: , assign button tag as index

```
cell.yourbutton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

2) Add target and action for your button as below.

```
[cell.yourbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

3) Code to action based on index as below in ViewControler.

```
-(void)yourButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender{
 [arrayOfTextVaule objectAtIndex:sender.tag];}
```

OR

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
yourCustomCell *selectedCell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"%@",selectedCell.label);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy... add label text to button accessibilityValue and recover it in the target method.

```
{
    UIButton * button = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    button.accessibilityValue = label.text;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(sendLabelString:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

-(void)sendLabelString:(UIButton*)sender{
     NSString * labelString = sender.accessibilityValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem as I understand:

1. You have custom cell with a UILabel and UIButton
2. On click, you want the title of the button to be the same as that of the label

The answer to the problem as just described:

1. You need to assign a tag to the label and the button so you can get a reference to them in the code. To do this:

   1.1. Go to the story board

   1.2. select the UILabel

   1.3. from the properties, you can find the tag property, give it a number (like 1 for instance)

   1.4. Go through 1.1 through 1.3 for the UIButton (give it tag number 2).
2. in the table view controller (the .m class file), add the following code:

   ```
   -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

       UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; // fetch an instance from the cell
       UILabel * lbl = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag: 1]; // fetch an instance of the label
       UIButton * btn = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag: 2]; // fetch an instance of the button
       btn.title = lbl.text; // I don't remember the text properties :D (figure it our yourself. it should be easy)
    }
   ```